# PHP MySQL - How to set the amount of scripts MySQL can manage at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that launches a little more than 100 other php scripts at the same time. I would like them to be executed at the same time, unfortunately their seem to be a queue as only a part is executed at the same time. So my question is simple. Is it possible to configure somewhere the number of php scripts MySQL can manage at the same time? Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Comment: how do you launch the 100 other scripts ? don't forget that php isn't multi threaded without pnctl extension

Comment: MySQL has nothing to do with PHP other than the fact that  you might be accessing MySQL from PHP, but to mysql its no different than any other client connecting whether that be the command line, Navicat, PHPMyAdmin, SequelPro or otherwise...

Comment: Hello Malko. I launch them through an ajax call that is placed in a loop that runs a bit more than 100 times (i use jquery for the ajax call)

Comment: Leaving aside the many other issues involved, what do these scripts actually *do*?  For example, if they're trying to update the same database record nothing you can do will force their execution to be precisely simultaneous (indeed, what outcome would you expect in such a situation?).  I think you need to define better what you mean by "at the same time".

Comment: The scripts gather information and insert new records into tables...

Comment: Is it one script being launched 100 times? InnoDB? MyISAM? Please show some SQL.

Comment: Yes it is one script, my tables are innodb and i use pdo

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute 100 processes at the same time, you need 100 cores. Unless your server has no 100 processors/cores, there is no way the scripts will be executed at the same time. In order the kernel to switch between them, you need to know how to write daemons and do not occupy too many resources in a single script. For example, put some sleeps, and while one script is sleeping, the OS will execute another, so the scripts will don't wait each other to finish, but will be run somehow simulatenously

Comment: Hello Darhazer. I do not totally get what you are saying. I have a mac dual core and not only 2 script are executed at the same time. Based on 'show full processlist' I have 5 scripts running at the same time. The other are on queue somewhere. But I would like it to be 100 running at the same time. What to do?

Comment: @marc: you would control that in the apache configuration file by configuring the `MaxClients`, `MaxServers`, `MaxRequests` and other directives appropriately. That said i have a feeling this is going to end horribly if youre depending upon 100 requests to run in parallel for a single user.

Comment: Hello prodigitalson. Do you know what I have to look for in it?

Comment: @prodigitalson. The thing is I am the only user. I run MAMP. I followed your instruction and went in the file httpd.config but did not found MaxClients... Is it in another file?

Comment: They are valid directives but maybe they arent in MAMP's distribution by default... I have no idea i use a MacPorts installation. But jsut because they arent there doesnt mean you cant add them.